# htaccess - Remove part of url - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Current `.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tried a few things from SO without any change.

```
RewriteRule ^/category(.*) /$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^/category(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ $1 [L,QSA]
```

The following URLs need to be changed.

```
http://example.com/iw-class/boxers/pro/ - remove iw-class
http://example.com/page/trainers/ - remove page
```

Comment: The ```^/category``` is a literal string, so you need to use ```RewriteRule ^/iw-class(.*) $1 [QSA]```

Comment: I actually got rid of category using some plugin. But the /page and /iw-class are still there. Tried this; `RewriteRule ^/iw-class(.*) $1 [QSA]`. All these changes go in the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>`?

Comment: There's not enough information to do a good job of answering this.  You're showing url's that could (or could not) be "built in" WP routes.  It is **not typical** for wordpress to use `/page/trainers` for pages - are you using custom posts?  If so, I don't think you'll be satisfied with htaccess rules that strip these out, they will likely cause issues with WP showing the right pages.

Comment: Yes. They are custom posts.